# Comma after reporting verbs

Tags: verbs, commas, indirect-speech

I am a bit confused after seeing some sample sentences. Is it correct not to place commas after the reporting verbs? For example:

> He indicated he was happy.
>
> He indicated, he was happy.

Which one is right?

Comment: If by *indicated* you mean that he *gave a signal about being happy*, then the first is correct. If you meant something like *he turned on the left indicator in his car because he was happy*, then the second is correct.

Answer (score 1):

A comma is absolutely out of place here.  However the first sentence could be improved.  I'd say, "He indicated that he was happy."